# Workflow in a loop

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I`m trying to create a workflow in SharePoint designer, to turn Pictures in to relative once posted on the blog.

However each time a post is created the workflow runs 5 times. Any ideas on how i could stop this?

Comment: What is the trigger condition set for workflow? you can check it under "workflow settings". 
Do you want to trigger the workflow only on item creation or both creation & update?
Also, are you updating the same item inside your workflow?

Comment: both creation & update i am updating 3 items

Comment: I have the workflow as my profile pic

Comment: @Jerry_MSFT could you please help?

Comment: @GaneshSanap could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

How do you setup the workflow? Is the trigger start workflow on item creation and update, and you have actions in your workflow updating the item? It is a common scenario which will cause a workflow loop. It this is not your situation, please provide more information about the list/library which your workflow is connected to, and the structure of your workflow including trigger and actions.

Comment: It triggers on each creation and update. And I have 3 actions running in the workflow. The workflow should  run once and only run again if something is changed. even when i set end work flow at the end of it. It will still runs 5 times

Comment: any one any ideas?

Comment: @Luana, As what Ganesh and I are concerning, do you update the list item in your 3 actions inside the workflow? If so, the new update on the item will also trigger a new run of the workflow

Comment: When posting there are 3 options available the creation of the URL, HP image and Banner image. on each post that stars with http the workflow should verify the links and remove the first 33 letters from the links. which list items do you mean?